# Java executing sql script anomaly ? Derby network server

Tags: java, mysql, derby

I have made two classes, a SQL reader and a SQL Compiler. For testing purposes I read in and executed a set of scripts which came with derby, the derbytutor folder. What I cant figure out is why no more than three scripts actually execute without a particular error occuring. This error being `A network protocol error was encountered and the connection has been terminated: A PROTOCOL Data Stream Syntax Error was detected.  Reason: 0x9,236. Plaintext connection attempt to an SSL enabled server?` I am running the java application as a Client with the Client/Server architecture. Also the scripts are quiet long if that could be a factor ?

The order of the scripts are as  follows:

1 - Make the schema (Runs fine no error)

2 - Insert Script1 - Runs fine

2 - Insert Script2 - Runs fine

3 - Third Script returns that error.Its not with the syntax otherwise it would of been apparent

Here is the main method which runs through the script conversion and execution

```
   scriptRead scriptBuffer = new scriptRead();
      scriptCompiler exec = new scriptCompiler();

       try {
        final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //Load Scripts
        String[] schema = scriptBuffer.getScript("schema.sql");  
        String[] t1 = scriptBuffer.getScript("t1.sql");
        String[] t2 = scriptBuffer.getScript("t2.sql");
        String[] t3 = scriptBuffer.getScript("t3.sql");

        scriptCompiler sc = new scriptCompiler();
        //Run scripts
        sc.execute(schema);  
        sc.execute(t1);
        sc.execute(t2);   
        sc.execute(t3);// Problem statement

        final long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long fin = end - start;
        System.out.println("Took a time... : " + fin);

    }catch(Throwable exc){
        System.err.print(exc.getMessage()+"\n");
    }
```

Here is the script execution code..

```
  public void makeConn() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
     Class.forName(driver);
     conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);  
  } 

  @SuppressWarnings("CallToThreadDumpStack")  
  public void execute(String[] query){

     try{
          makeConn();
          try{
             stmt = conn.createStatement();
             for(int x = 0; x < query.length;x++){
                stmt.execute(query[x]);    
             }
          stmt.close();
          closeConn();
         }catch(SQLException err){
           //err.printStackTrace();
             System.err.println(err.getMessage());
         }
   }catch(Throwable e){
      if(e instanceof SQLException){
           if(((SQLException)e).equals("08001")){
                System.err.println( "Incorrect Username or Password");
            }else{
                System.err.println( "Check Server is running");
            }
      }else{
            System.err.println("Could not find class path");
      }
  } 

}
```

I really have no idea where the problems lies ? If it was SQL Syntax fair enough, but then why are the other scripts executing.

Answer (score 0):

Three ideas to start your diagnosis:

1. Completely examine the client-side exception: http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UnwindExceptionChain
2. Examine your derby.log for your Derby server. Sometimes, errors are reported only there, and are not properly conveyed back to the client.
3. Is it always t3.sql which fails? Examine that file closely. Look in particular for strange characters, quotation marks, punctuation, etc. Something that would throw off the low-level parsing.

Comment: Well the only difference is that the third insert script contains more types. So the first script is something like `insert into COUNTRIES values ( 'Afghanistan','AF','Asia');` AND the failing scripts are `insert into FLIGHTAVAILABILITY values ('AA1211',1,'2004-03-31',2,2,2);`. Also that site is under maintenance so couldn't see it